# C reading string content from file and compare equality

Tags: c

I am reading content from a file and I am expecting to look for a particular value, say "london". for this I am reading the content, tokenize it by "\n", then compare each value against "london" using "strcmp".

But I think I still do not understand how C stores data and does comparison and therefore my code below does not work as i expect. I guess I am missing some fundamental knowledge of C here, please help:

TEST COMMAND LINE:

```
./myprogram datafile.txt "london"
```

INPUT datafile.txt:

```
london
manchester
britain
...
```

CODE myprogram.c:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE* fl;
  char st1[2000];
  char * buffer = 0;
  long length;

  fl = fopen (argv[1], "r"); //the data file content is shown above
  if (fl){
    fseek (fl, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (fl);
    fseek (fl, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc (length+1);
    if (buffer){
        //fread (buffer, 1, length, fl);
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), length, fl);
        buffer[length] = '\0';
    }
  fclose (fl);    
  }else{
    printf("data file not found");
    return -1;
  }  


  //firstly let's compare the value passed by command line with "london"
  strcpy(st1, argv[2]); 
  if(strcmp(st1,"london")==0)
    printf("equals\n");  //as expected, I get "equals" printed
  else
    printf("unequal\n");


  //now let's compare the values extracted from the data file, 
  char* entity = strtok(buffer, "\n"); 
  while (entity != NULL) {
    strcpy(st1, entity); //copy the value from the char pointer entity to the char array st1 so we can compare with other strings

    printf("%s\n", st1);  //this prints london, ....

    if(strcmp(st1,"london")==0)
        printf("equals\n");  //I was expecting this..
    else
        printf("unequal\n"); //but i got this...
    entity = strtok(NULL, "\n");
  }
  return 0;
```

}

I am expecting output from the above program to be:

```
equals
london
equals
manchester
unequal
britain
unequal
...
```

but I dont understand why I am getting

```
equals
london
unequal  <=============== why and how to fix?
manchester
unequal
britain
unequal
...
```

And how should I change it so the value "london" read from the file equals the actual "string" of "london"?

Many thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. What system are you on, what compiler and compilation options? For me, it's OS X 10, clang-602.0.53, options `-Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99`.

Comment: Do you have by accident a trailing space in your input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the following things and I replace the call of `strcpy` by `strncpy`. Your initial problem was the '\0' at the end of `st1` variable. So you can do this :

```
  while (entity != NULL) {
    strncpy(st1, entity,strlen(entity)-1); //copy the value from the char pointer entity to the char array st1 so we can compare with other strings

    printf("%s\n", st1);  //this prints london, ....

    if(!strcmp(st1,"london"))
        printf("equals\n");  //I was expecting this..
    else
        printf("unequal\n"); //but i got this...
    entity = strtok(NULL, "\n");
  }
```

Or the other solution is to put the '\0' yourself at the end of `st1` like this :

```
strcpy(st1, entity);
st1[strlen(entity)-1] = '\0';
```

I test the both and it's working.

Comment: `strtok` should replace the separator token (in this case, a `'\n'`) by a NUL character, so the string is NUL terminated. From the man page: "The strtok() and strtok_r() functions return a pointer to the beginning of each subsequent token in the string, after replacing the token itself with a NUL character.". So it should not be necessary to append a NUL character yourself. The `strncpy` option may work in case there happens to be a missed trailing space in the input file (but then the input file should have been sanitized, not the routine adjusted).

Comment: With ``strncpy``, I didn't have the problem to put the NUL character at the end (and at the same occasion, thank you for the remark for the strtok function), this is why I put a NUL character at the end after the call to ``strcpy``.

Comment: Thanks, very thorough explanation, my problem is solved!

Comment: You're welcome :) (can you mark the problem as solved if my answer is the good one please)