# What is the best way to read a file and then compare a string to what is in that file?

Tags: c

What is the best way to read a file and then compare a string to what is in that file? I have been trying to figure this out for days now and I am just stumped on how to do it. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: do you want to find a string which occurs in a text file, or match a whole text file with a string?  Some more context would also be helpful.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430884/c-reading-string-content-from-file-and-compare-equality?rq=1

Comment: I am going to take in a character string and an integer. I then want to compare those to what I already have in the file. In the file there are names and ID numbers.

Comment: I have tried to read the file then take in the input and then compare that input to the file contents using strcmp.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  At the very least, you should show us what you've got in the way of code, and the sample data you expect to work with, and the desired output (and, if your code has got that far, what you're currently getting as output).  Are you meant to be using the standard I/O library (`fopen()` et al) or the Unix file descriptor functions (system calls) such as `open()` and `read()`?  There's not enough information in the question to show us what you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question outlines in broad terms reading a *string* from a file, and making a string comparison with another *string*. To read from your file, you must first open the file for reading. For reading text from a file, your normal choice in C is `fopen` to open a stream and asign the return to a `FILE` pointer which can be used with the collection of *stream reading functions* found in the standard library. (e.g. `fgetc`, `fgets`, `fscanf`, `getline`, etc..)

Your job is to open a file, validate it is open, read the needed information from the file, and then close the file. To accomplish this, you will need to prepare a buffer (character array, or allocated block of memory) with sufficient space to hold the information read from the file (`+1 char` for the *nul-terminating* character). Without the *nul-terminating* character, you have an *array of characters* and not a valid *string*) A short example could be:

```
char buf[256] = {0};  /* char array to hold 255 chars + nul-terminating char */
FILE *fp = NULL;      /* FILE pointer to hold return of fopen */

fp = fopen (filename, "r"); /* open file for reading    */
if (fp == NULL) {           /* if not open throw error  */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed 'filename'.\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If you are reading a single string without included spaces from the file, you can simply read the first word with `fscanf` into `buf`. `fscanf` returns the number of successful conversion that match the given *format specifier*. Use the *field width* option with your *format specifier* to insure you read no more than your buffer will hold (e.g. `"%255s"`) saving room for the *nul-terminating* char at the end. Use the return from `fscanf` to validate your read:

```
if (fscanf (fp, "%255s", buf) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: fscanf read failure from 'filename'.\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    
}
```

If the string you are reading from the file can include *whitespace*, then you either need to modify your `fscanf` *format specifier*, (e.g. `"%255[...]"`, where the *character class* `[...]` describes an expression to match your needed information) or use one of *line-oriented* stream functions (`fgets` or `getline`) to read an entire line from the file into `buf` and then parse `buf` as needed within the file. For example if the first line in the file included text separated by a *comma*:

```
The quick brown fox, jumps over the lazy dog.
```

and you need to compare the information appearing before the comma with a test string, you could do something like:

```
char str[256] = {0};    /* string to hold chars parsed from buf */
if (fgets (buf, 256, fp) == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: fgets read failure from 'filename'.\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    
}

if (sscanf (buf, "%[^,]", str) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: sscanf no conversion made.\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    
}
```

Finally, to compare if the strings are equal, the normal choice is to use `strcmp`. Two strings are equal if the return of the comparison by `strcmp` is `0`. You can implement the test like:

```
if (strcmp (str, teststr) == 0) /* test if strings are equal */
    printf ("\n string  : %s\n teststr : %s  EQUAL\n", str, teststr);
else
    printf ("\n string  : %s\n teststr : %s  DIFFER\n", str, teststr);
```

Which would perform the test with `strcmp` and print the string read from the file and the teststr and whether the strings are EQUAL or DIFFER.

You can put all the pieces together as follows. (note: the program takes the filename as the first argument, but by using a simple `ternary` operator, will use a default filename of `data.txt` if no filename is given -- `stdin` can be substituted for `"data.txt"` to read from `stdin` by default):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[256] = {0};  /* char array to hold 255 chars + null-terminating char */
    char str[256] = {0};  /* string to hold chars parsed from buf */
    char *teststr = "The quick brown fox";  /* string literal for comparison */
    FILE *fp = NULL;      /* FILE pointer to hold return of fopen */

    fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "data.txt", "r");  /* open file for reading    */
    if (fp == NULL) {                                   /* if not open throw error  */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed 'filename'.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fgets (buf, 256, fp) == NULL) { /* read 1 line from file */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fgets read failure from 'filename'.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    
    }
    fclose (fp);            /* close file when reading complete */

    if (sscanf (buf, "%[^,]", str) != 1) {  /* parse up to ',' into str */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: sscanf no conversion made.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    
    }

    if (strcmp (str, teststr) == 0) /* test if strings are equal */
        printf ("\n string  : %s\n teststr : %s  EQUAL\n", str, teststr);
    else
        printf ("\n string  : %s\n teststr : %s  DIFFER\n", str, teststr);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/qbfcomma.txt
The quick brown fox, jumps over the lazy dog.
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_strcmp dat/qbfcomma.txt

 string  : The quick brown fox
 teststr : The quick brown fox  EQUAL
```

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

**Note:** you could simply use `fscanf` with the *format specifier* `"%255[^,]"` to read the same information into `buf` and then simply test `buf` against `teststr` without the need to parse the line into `str` using `sscanf`. But it is important to note that the normal approach is to use a *line-oriented* (reading a line at a time) and then parsing the needed information from the line within your code. This will avoid a number of pitfalls that arise from using `fscanf` or when trying to shoehorn all pattern matching into a `fscanf` format specifier. It also allows additional methods of parsing the needed information from the buffer (such as using pointer arithmetic, etc..).